# How do White Walkers communicate with humans?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I haven't heard any words from a White Walker or the Night King. But there may be some hidden language or some kind of sound by which they communicate to each other.

Can they communicate with humans?

If yes then how?

If no then how did the deal between Craster and Night king happen, that they'll not harm his keep if he keeps donating him his male babies?

Comment: According to google, "Skroth" is indeed the official name of the language used by the White Walkers. i don't think so they communicate with humans, your question is nice that how did the deal between Craster and Night king happen!!

Comment: @RuchaBhatt I believe the D&D went back on that decision over than language name but I can't remember where I read that.

Comment: Related - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/can-white-walkers-talk?rq=1

Comment: Also on SF&F - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156172/how-did-the-arrangement-between-the-white-walkers-and-craster-begin

Comment: @TheLethalCoder maybe you read it here in [another related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79426/1190)

Comment: "If no then how did the deal between Craster and Night king happen" - that assumes there was an actual agreement, as opposed to word of mouth millennia-old superstitious traditions that seem to work, and might be referred to as a "deal" in a broader sense when explaining why it is done.

Comment: As to how a deal between Craster and the Walkers can be struck without speaking: Walkers crash Craster's party. Craster fears being killed, but the Walkers take his sons and leave. This happens a second time. The third time, Craster puts his sons outside and notices that the Walkers no longer crash his party. Problem solved, and Craster can consider that as a fair deal since he has no use for boys anyway. The Walker may have **intentionally** not killed Craster the first time because they were aware of his... breeding habits. It's a steady supply of babies for them, no point in killing Craster

Answer (score 2):

## We Don't Know

We know the wights can at least scream as we saw in Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall".

From [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36612/45378) sourced from [the wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Skroth) they use a language name Skroth. Though the language was never used on screen at the time of it's naming.

> The credits for episodes of Season 1 of the TV series include the statement: "Dothraki, Ashai'i, and **Skroth** languages created by the Language Creation Society and David J. Peterson."
>
> Peterson developed a spoken language for the White Walkers to use in Season 1 (probably in the unaired pilot episode), but it was **not ultimately used on-screen**, and **dropped entirely from Season 2**. Instead, actual ice-cracking sound effects were used when the White Walkers are conversing.
>
> In an interview with Entertainment Weekly during Season 2, Executive Producers David Benioff and D.B. Weiss **stated that "Skroth" is indeed the official name of the language** used by the White Walkers.

In Season 2 Episode 10, "Valar Morghulis" we do see a White Walker use hand signals as it passes Sam. It screams/shrieks too so this could be confirmation of it speaking in Skroth.

However, it appears that Skroth was scrapped though there are conflicting statements.

> Also, the information on Skroth there [Wikia] is wrong. I created something for the White Walkers initially called Skroth, and I believe they didn’t end up using it. And that was for season 1; I didn’t do anything for it for season 2.
>
> <sub>— David J. Peterson, "Ei Mahrazhi’th Drivoe", [Dothraki.com](http://www.dothraki.com/2012/06/ei-mahrazhith-drivoe/)</sub>

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156186/58193) over on Sci-Fi goes into detail of the books of how the agreement could have come about though it boils down to we don't know. As for the show, well we have even less information so we don't know at all.